# How to convert timestamp to AWS data lake s3 timestamp

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, data-lake

In my data frame I have timestamp column with values in format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%m". I want to save this Data Frame to parquet using:
 `df.write.partitionBy('p_timestamp').mode("overwrite").parquet('output/proto.parquet')`
and I want to have timestamp partition saved in AWS data lake s3 timestamp format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M"

I tried:

```
df.select(F.col("p_timestamp"), F.date_format(F.col("p_timestamp"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M").alias("date_format")).show()
```

but I got an error:
`Illegal pattern character 'T'`

I would be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the formatting string you are looking for is:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm"
```

You get the error because the `T` is not quoted with `'` to mark it as a string.
You can consult sparks [Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) if you need something a little different.

Small example:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("Time", T.StringType(), False)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1970-09-01 02:02:10',)], schema=schema)
df.withColumn("Convert", F.date_format(F.col("Time"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm")).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+----------------+
|               Time|         Convert|
+-------------------+----------------+
|1970-09-01 02:03:10|1970-09-01T02-03|
+-------------------+----------------+
```